# How can the average employment value be calculated or generated for three types of values within a variable?

Tags: stata

I want to generate or calculate the average employment value for all three age groups (15+, 15-24, 25+) for each year for each country (five countries) for male and female. What are the exact command to use?

It didn't work when I wrote: egen averageemployment = mean( Female Male), by (Age)

Comment: You need to provide more detail for this to be answerable. Is your dataset at the individual level or some grouped level (ie, is each observation/row an individual?)? What is the name of the variable which indicates employment status, and is it a dummy variable or something else? How are the `Female`, `Male`, and `Age` variables defined?

Comment: The dataset is in a grouped level, each observation/row represent employment value for each country, for each age group, each sex and year. The name of the variable is just called employment value, those who are employed, and not a dummy variable. Female and male variables are defined as employment values. Age is defined as "15+", "15-24", "25+". Year is defined as the years from 2000-2023. Country is defined as all the countries.

Comment: Thanks, this helps! For future reference, this information should be in the main body of the question (providing a data example would be better). I don't understand what you want to do, because it sounds like the employment value (reported separately under the `male` and `female` variable) is already at the year-country-agegroup level in your dataset. When you say you want the average for each age group, year and country, what do you want to average across?

Comment: Do you mean you only want the average employment value *by age group*, averaging across all countries, genders, and years? Then you need to tell us what the employment value is. Is it a rate? A count? Something else? Depending on your answer, this might not be possible without extra information such as population counts for each row.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It's my first post and I'm new here. To confirm you, yes, the employment value is reported separately under the male and female variable and is already at the year-country-age group level in my dataset. Each year and each country cover the employment value for male and female for each three age group. I need the average or mean employment value for all three age groups.

Comment: Here is the link to the dataset (called: Employment by sex and age ILO modelled estimates (thousands) - annual): https://www.ilo.org/shinyapps/bulkexplorer46/?lang=en&segment=indicator&id=UNE_2EAP_SEX_AGE_RT_A

Comment: The link is not to a Stata file. It's essential to give us an example of how the data appear in a Stata dataset. You can use Stata command `dataex` for that purpose.

Comment: @Zeinab, thanks. I suggest you use the "Total" employment rate for each country for each age group, and do not use the male/female disaggregation. To calculate a proper average from the male/female stats, you'd need to know the number of people (in the labour force? working age pop?) in each age-group by sex, to appropriately weight your average. 

Using "Total", you can maybe take the average across countries and years, with something like `egen aveemp = mean(Total), by(Age)`. Note that here we are weighting each country & year equally, which is common practice but affects interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with the comment that unit of observation and (mock) example data would been helpful. But this is probalby a solution to your question.

You can adsd other variables in the `by()` but I kept my example simple.

```
clear
input float(id age) str3 country float employment
 1 0 "ABC" 1
 2 1 "ABC" 1
 3 2 "ABC" 1
 4 1 "ABC" 1
 5 0 "ABC" 0
 6 2 "ABC" 1
 7 1 "XYZ" 1
 8 2 "XYZ" 1
 9 2 "XYZ" 0
10 1 "XYZ" 0
11 0 "XYZ" 1
12 1 "XYZ" 0
end

preserve
    collapse (mean) employment_mean = employment , by(age country)
   
    tempfile employmean
    save `employmean'
restore

merge m:1 age country using `employmean'
```

Comment: If the data structure is like this one can just do it in one line using `egen employment_mean = mean(employment), by(age country)` rather than collapsing, saving and merging back in.

Comment: the employment value is defined under female and male variables.

Comment: @joshb I tried that but "employment" is not defined as a variable. The structure of the dataset looks like this: there are five columns. Country: with the name of the countries, age: with age groups (15+, 15-24, 25+) year: with the year. female: with the employment values, and male with the employment values